# Generate 3D data using 2D images

Tags: visual-c++, vtk, itk

I have a folder of 2D jpg images. I would like to convert that images to 3D image so that i can generate Digital Radiograph using ITK.

I know that it is easy to convert the 2D images to DICOM format and by using vtkDICOMImageReader, an then to give the output of  vtkDICOMImageReader to the itk's DRR.
But i don't want that because my 2D images have no  information about series number, instance number, image position patient,etc.

Is there any way to give the folder of 2D jpg images to the input of ITK's DRR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series of 2D images does not have to be in DICOM format. [ImageSeriesReadWrite example](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.2.0/Examples/IO/ImageSeriesReadWrite.cxx) shows how to do it for PNGs. Changing the [file name format](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.2.0/Examples/IO/ImageSeriesReadWrite.cxx#L126) to match your JPEGs should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. But will the itk raycast interpolate  image function take the output of reader as input?

Comment: The output of the reader will be a 3D `itk::Image`. I assume that's what the DRR generation wants.